# What is the distribution of angles for a point uniform on the unit $n$ sphere?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, spherical-geometry

Take $x$ uniform on the unit sphere in $n+1$ dimensions. $x$ can be represented as $n$ angles, one from $0$ to $2\pi$ and the others in $[0,\pi)$.

What is the joint distribution of these angles? I know they are not uniformly distributed in this space. (If they were, then caps would be overrepresented)

Are the angles independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, but a good one, and one that has some interesting connections across topics that might seem unrelated- the uniform distribution on the n-sphere has a relationship derived in information geometry to the Jeffreys prior for multinomial probabilities- taking the square root of probabilities results in a diffeomorphism between the unit simplex and the unit sphere, and the Jeffreys' prior after transformation is uniform.

The easiest way to approach this is to start with a uniform probability density in Euclidean space, and then to apply a transformation to get the spherical coordinates- which, through the Jacobian of the inverse transformation, gives us the pdf in spherical coordinates. If X is uniform on the n-sphere (n+1 coordinates but with a restricted length), the uniform distribution is proportional to the reciprocal of n-volume of that sphere. Since this is constant, and the radius of the sphere is unimportant to the angular coordinates, I'll restrict my attention to the unit n-sphere and drop the normalization constant (though I will come back to that). For now, the relevant information is that the density is constant.

The conversion from Cartesian coordinates to spherical is straightforward, and the [Wikipedia article on the n-sphere](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) gives a good overview. Recall that the distribution of a function of random variables $y = g(X)$ is given by $f(g^{-1} (y)) \det{J}$, where $f$ is the original pet and $J$ is the Jacobian of the inverse transformation $g^{-1}$. Since f is constant, we need only consider the Jacobian. Since we have

$$x_i = \sin(\phi_1)\sin(\phi_2)\ldots\sin(\phi_{i-1})\cos(\phi_i)$$

Conveniently, the Jacobian is upper triangular, so we only need the product of the diagonal entries.

$$\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial \phi_i} = -\prod_{j=1}^{i} \sin(\phi_j)$$

Taking the absolute value of the product of all the entries, we get

$$f(\vec{\phi}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \sin(\phi_i)^{n-i+1} $$

Which is the answer we're looking for. As a sanity check, if we had a uniform distribution on the n-sphere, then the conditional distribution of the remaining coordinates conditioned on the first k should be the uniform distribution on the (n- k)-sphere, which we can easily verify.

The normalization constant is unchanged by the coordinate transformation, so all that's left is to divide by the volume of the n-sphere.

Comment: First paragraph is very interesting, thanks for the answer.